Is this provable? $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin (\pi \cos^2 x)}{x^2}=\pi $
I came across this question
$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin (\pi \cos^2 x)}{x^2}=\pi $$
I tried following method simplify it into a $x\to0$, $\sin x / x$ type limit
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin(\pi \cos^2 x)}{\pi \cos^2 x}\cdot\frac{\pi \cos^2 x}{x^2} $$
But, still no luck. Any suggestions or tips to solve this. (the exercise book told you shouldn't use L'hopitals)

Please use MathJax. Here is a
tutorial.

Your work didn't work because the angle of $\sin$ in your limit is not $0$ when you  substitute  zero in it.

Does this answer your question? What is $\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin(\pi \cos^2x)}{x^2}= \ ?$ - found using an Approach0 search. Note there are other duplicates, e.g., Limit $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin\left(\pi\cos^2(x)\right)}{x^2}$  (where its answer mainly just gives a hint rather than fully solving the problem), ...

(cont.) Calculation of $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\sin (\pi\cos^2 x)}{x^2}$ (which has no answer), etc. Last, but not least, welcome to Math SE.

Using $\cos^2 x+\sin^2x=1$ and $\sin(\pi-a)=\sin a $ you have:
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin(\pi \cos^2 x)}{x^2}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin(\pi-\pi\sin^2x)}{x^2}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin(\pi \sin^2x)}{\pi \sin^2x}\frac{\pi \sin^2 x}{x^2} $$
Can you continue from here?

Excellent. I like this answer.

$$\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin (\pi \cos^2x-\pi)}{x^2}=\lim\limits_{x\to 0}-\frac{\sin(\pi \cos^2 x)}{x^2}$$
$$\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin (\pi \cos^2x-\pi)}{x^2}=\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{-\pi \sin ^2x }{x^2}=-\pi$$
